# Sharing data returned from rest call between sibling components in Angular 4

Tags: angular, rxjs

This is my main component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../my-service.service';
import { DataShareService } from '../data-share-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  private myCustomer: Object;

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  ngOnInit() {    
    this.getMyCustomerProfile();
    console.log("In Home: " + JSON.stringify(this.myCustomer)); // this prints undefined - why ?

    // this.dataShareService.currentCustomer.subscribe(customer => this.customer = customer);
    // this.dataShareService.changeCustomer(this.customer);
  }

  private getMyCustomerProfile(){
    this.myService.getProfile()
    .subscribe(
      customer => {
          this.myCustomer = customer;
          console.log("In Home: " + JSON.stringify(this.myCustomer)); // this prints the returned json properly
      },
      error => {
          console.log("Error fetching user profile!");
      });

     console.log("In Home: " + JSON.stringify(this.myCustomer)); // this prints undefined - why ?    
  }
}
```

`MyService` `getProfile` method is a rest call:

```
getProfile(){
  return this.http.get(this.config.myUrl + 'mycustomer/', this.options).map((response: Response) => response.json());
 }
```

**Question 1:** Why does the `console.log` inside `getMyCustomerProfile's` `subscribe` method prints the returned object json correctly but the other two `console.log` prints `undefined` ?

**Question 2:** Also, how do I share the returned Object in above component with Sibling component (and not child component) using shared service ?

I tried below, but its not working.

Shared Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DataShareService {

  private customerSource = new BehaviorSubject<Object>("default customer");
  currentCustomer = this.customerSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeCustomer(customer: Object){
    console.log("In Service: "+customer);
    this.customerSource.next(customer);
  }
}
```

Sibling:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataShareService } from '../data-share-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sibling',
  templateUrl: './sibling.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sibling.component.css']
})
export class SiblingComponent implements OnInit {

  private myCustomer: Object;

  constructor(private dataShareService: DataShareService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataShareService.currentCustomer.subscribe(customer => this.myCustomer = customer);
  }
}
```

The HTML Template for both `HomeComponent` and `SiblingComponent` is printing a property from the returned object:

```
Welcome {{myCustomer?.name}}
```

This prints correctly in `HomeComponent` but not in `SiblingComponent`. Meaning the data is not getting shared. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martin for the inputs.

Updating my getMyCustomerProfile method to following worked:

```
 private getMyCustomerProfile(){
    this.myService.getProfile()
    .subscribe(
      customer => {
          this.dataShareService.changeCustomer(customer);
      },
      error => {
          console.log("Error fetching user profile!");
      });
  }
```

And subscribing the same in both Sibling and main component with the following line:

```
this.dataShareService.currentCustomer.subscribe(customer => this.customer = customer);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It's all asynchronous. When you use `console.log` outside `subscribe` (or basically outside the operator chain) it'll be called before any value is emitted and therefore it's `undefined`.
2. Just assign the value into a property in the service class:

   ```
   .subscribe(customer => this.myService.myCustomer = customer)
   ```

   If you need the sibling components to be able to react when the `myCustomer` changes asynchronously make it a `BehaviorSubject` (or `ReplaySubject(1)` would in this case do the same).

   ```
   .subscribe(customer => this.myService.myCustomer.next(customer))
   ```

Comment: For data sharing, I did what you are saying. Please see the commented lines in ngInit() method of AppComponent.... But that is not working...

Comment: That's almost it. Then you need to call `changeCustomer` in the subscribe callback instead of `this.myCustomer = customer;`

Comment: Do you mean the console.log statement inside getCustomerProfile's Subscribe method (which is printing correctly) will be replaced by this.dataShareService.changeCustomer(this.customer); ???

Comment: No, you need to replace this `this.myCustomer = customer;`